# Eval Error with session in asp:Image control

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I want to bind image with session variable.If session is not set yet(EMPTY) it will bind to default value and session is not then session variable.

I tried this

```
<asp:image runat="server" id="Image1" ImageUrl='<%# Eval(Session.Count==0?"DefaultValue":Session["ProfilePicLink"].ToString() )%> %>' AlternateText="admin" />
```

But it is showing error.
What is wrong ?How to apply condtion in EVAL

Comment: is this inside a datalist? or gridview?

Comment: Inside site.Master

Comment: Just bind image location with database ...Session["ProfilePicLink"]  contains link of image from database

Comment: then why are you using eval. why dont you just use <%= Session["ProfilePicLink"]==null?"DefaultValue‌​":Session["ProfilePicLink"].ToString()%>

Comment: Thats solves the problem.Thanks ....

Comment: please mark as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why dont you just use <%= Session["ProfilePicLink"]==null?"DefaultValue‌​‌​":Session["ProfilePicLink"].ToString()%>

Answer (score 0):

before using Session variable always check it for null values by doing this code

```
if(Session["ProfilePicLink"]!=null)
{
//Use your session variable here
}
```

Comment: was this helpful?